# Deploying maven java web project in netbeans on a remote glassfish server is failing

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, remote-server, glassfish-4

I have a java web project working fine on my local glassfish server. I need to deploy it to a remote glassfish server using netbeans so I setup the server on an AWS instance of ubuntu and successfully connected it with netbeans.

I am able to see the resources under the server in netbeans services pane but when am trying to deploy the project, its failing with following logs:

**Running Log:**

```
Deploying on GlassFish Server (AWS)
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Distributing /xxxx/xxx/yyyy/target/yyyy-1.0.war
GlassFish Server (AWS), deploy, null, false
```

**IDE Log:**

```
INFO [glassfish]: Requested Entity: public id = -//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN, system id = http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.tooling.admin.RunnerHttpDeploy]: IO exception caught in handleSend() method:
java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3518)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3501)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:255)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:377)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.tooling.admin.RunnerHttpDeploy.handleSend(RunnerHttpDeploy.java:267)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.tooling.admin.Runner.handleHTTPConnection(Runner.java:828)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.tooling.admin.Runner.call(Runner.java:939)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.tooling.admin.Runner.call(Runner.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:259)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:93)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:315)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

**Server Log:**

```
-- nothing --
```

The IDE is telling me to check the server logs for more details but server does not have any logs (I cleared  the logfile before deploying the project, so there is no server stating info but it is running fine as I am able to access it from the browser and cmdline).

One more things, though the version of both the servers are same, the remote server only have web profile installed whereas the local is the installation done along with netbeans.

The config details are:

- Project - Maven web app
- Netbeans 8.2
- Glassfish 4.1.1
- Remote OS: Ubuntu 16 LTS
- Local OS: Fedora 25

Please ask for any more info required.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you setup secure admin on the glassfish server? `asadmin change-admin-password` + `asadmin enable-secure-admin`

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, I was able to resolve that and it worked quite fine until it was removed when I reformatted the system. I don't have the exact configuration now but I can confirm that it works. If you are stuck at a particular step, maybe I can help but I would like to mention that its not worth the effort (I realised it when I stopped using it) cause it is very slow compared to other ways we can achieve the same goal.